# Showing Sum of amount based on another row value on SESSION

Tags: php, session

I have view cart session like this

```
ID  NAME DISC     QTY
--  ---- ------  ------
1   AAAA  D1      2
1   AAAA  D5      1
2   BBBB  D1      1
1   AAAA  D1      1
```

What I want is, showing a query session with result like this

```
NAME  TOTAL
----  ------
AAAA   4
BBBB   1
```

How can I do this?

I have a query like this for show cart:

```
<?php
 if(count($_SESSION[data1][ID])>0)
      for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION[data1][ID]);$i++)
      {
          if($_SESSION[data1][ID][$i]!='')
          { ?>

       <td ><?=$_SESSION[data1][ID][$i]?></td>
       <td ><?=$_SESSION[data1][NAME][$i]?></td>
       <td ><?=$_SESSION[data1][DISC][$i]?></td>
       <td ><?=$_SESSION[data1][QTY][$i]?></td>

<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: -where i take "GROUP BY" ??

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through the data adding the quantities to an array indexed by the name.

Quick'n'dirty example

```
<?php
$names = array("AAA", "BBB", "AAA", "BBB");
$qts = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

for ($i=0; $i<count($names); $i++)
{
  $res[$names[$i]] += $qts[$i];
}

$k = array_keys($res);

for ($i=0; $i<count($k); $i++)
{
  echo $k[$i] . ":" . $res[$k[$i]] . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

> AAA:4
>   BBB:6

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array `$resultArray` and take `$_SESSION['data1']` in foreach loop, and check if ID does exists in `$resultArray`, if yes, append it, other wise create it.

```
<?php
$resultArray = array();
if(count($_SESSION['data1'])>0){

    foreach($_SESSION['data1'] as $data){
        if(isset($resultArray[$data['ID']])){
            $resultArray[$data['ID']] += $data['QTY'];
        } else {
            $resultArray[$data['ID']] = $data['QTY'];
        }
    }
}
print_r($resultArray); //check out result
?>
```